# How can I point Nextflow to the correct singularity binary?

Tags: conda, singularity-container, nextflow

I have a Nextflow workflow which I run from a conda environment (which also has singularity installed):

```yaml
name: nextflow
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - nextflow
  - singularity
```

The relevant snippet on `nextflow.config` is:

```
profiles {
    local {
        executor {
            name = "local"
        }
        includeConfig 'configs/local.config'
    }

    singularity {
        // Included since conda is still needed for some processes
        conda.enabled = true
        timeout = '2 h'
        // singularity-specific configs
        singularity.enabled = true
        singularity.autoMounts = true
        includeConfig 'configs/singularity.config'
    }
}
```

Before running my workflow, I activate the `nextflow` Conda environment. Still, when I run the workflow, I get:

```
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'preprocessing:fastpTrimming (5)'

Caused by:
  Process `cleaning_stuff` terminated with an error exit status (127)

Command executed:

  command --option --another_option -out /some/path

Command exit status:
  127

Command output:
  (empty)

Command error:
  env: 'singularity': No such file or directory

Work dir:
  /path/to/work/dir

Tip: view the complete command output by changing to the process work dir and entering the command `cat .command.out`

 -- Check '.nextflow.log' file for details
```

It seems Nextflow doesn't “see” singularity installed via Conda.
How can I point Nextflow to the correct singularity binary?

Comment: `singularity` does not appear to be in your `$PATH` when the job is run. How are you running Nextflow? Are you using the local [executor](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/executor.html) or something else?

Comment: Um...you shouldn't ever install the `conda` package anywhere other than **base** environment.

Comment: @Steve I am running it via local executor, Nextflow is installed via conda.

Comment: @pietro_molina But why do you need `conda` in your environment.yaml if you're only going to use `singularity` to run the jobs? You didn't include your nextflow.config, so we're assuming yours includes something like `singularity.enabled = true`.

Comment: @Steve I do not have singularity containers for all tools yet, so I still need conda for some things. I will include a snippet with my `nextflow.config`. Still, I removed it from the environment since the conda problem was related to one specific node.

Comment: @Steve I am starting to believe that the problem is related to my node. I would delete the question for now and reactivate it if I can rule out a problem on the local node.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to mix using Singularity containers and Conda environments within a single `nextflow` execution. I think using `conda.enabled = true` inside your *singularity* config profile might be problematic here. If you're using the local executor and don't yet specify a [`container`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#container) directive for all processes, simply install the required tools/packages (for which you don't yet have containers for) into your local *nextflow* conda environment.

Note that the Bioconda build system also builds Docker containers and these are uploaded to [quay.io](https://quay.io/) as part of the [Biocontainers project](https://quay.io/organization/biocontainers). Since Singularity/Apptainer can pull Docker containers, you may like to use one or more of these containers in your workflow. For example, in your nextflow.config`:

```
process {

    withName: 'fastpTrimming' {

        container = 'quay.io/biocontainers/fastp:0.23.4--hadf994f_2'
    }

    ...
}
```